# How can I detect what is causing a performance hit and sound lag on Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, lag

I have a brand new powerful Sony Vaio with Windows 7 Professional but I still experience very often lags in sound when playing videos in VLC, Flash videos, Spotify, Skype. I try external speakers / no external speakers it lags everywhere.

Has anyone heard this problem or any ideas how to fix it? I assume I have latest drivers as the system has been pre-installed by manufacturer.

Could it be hardware fault?

Answer (score 1):

I would not assume you have all of the latest drivers.  I would check to make sure you do and update the ones you don't (MOBO, sound card to be specific).  Also, are you using any other programs that may cause general system lag, like McAfee anti-virus or something?

This probably should be a comment but, I can't add them yet.